# Pass .aspx page textbox values to app.js file

Tags: office-365-developer, apps-development, office-365-develop-tool, developer

I am holding html text boxes in .aspx pages and want to pass the text box values into app.js file.

```
<tr>
  <td>Business Phone</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="txtbusinessphone" /></td>
</tr>
```

I had Written the below line in my app.js file ,But finding no luck to get the values.Can any one help me in solving this

```
var InterfaceElements = document.getElementById('<%=txtFirstname.ClientID%>').value;
```

Comment: Is this in a SharePoint-hosted app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using some ASP.NET syntax that doesn't work in JavaScript.

If you want to get the value of the HTML input shown in your markup, the JavaScript code would be:

```
var phone = document.getElementById('txtbusinessphone').value;
```

If you were using jQuery it would be:

```
var phone = jQuery('#txtbusinessphone').val();
```